# Move fields from row to column in PivotTable

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I've created a Excel PivotTable from a SAP HANA Analytical View and it looks like this:

[image: This is the screenshot of the table]

Now what I want is to position one of my value fields that is currently displayed as a ROW to display as a COLUMN.

Can we change the row key attribute to column and if not do we make the changes on the PivotTable or in SAP HANA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a different pivot table layout, like Tabular or Outline (**not** Compact), and turn off the subtotals. If I understand your needs correctly, this will look the way you want it.

[image: pivot layout]

Comment: Thank You! Works For Me!